# how to create multiple instances in django?

Tags: django

```
def form_creation(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        eventlist=request.POST.getlist('events')
        print(eventlist)
        for e in eventlist:
            form=Registration_Form(request.POST)
            form.username= request.POST['username']
            form.email= request.POST['email']
            form.phone_number=request.POST['phone_number']
            form.college_name=request.POST['college_name']
            form.year=request.POST['year']
            form.events=EventClass.objects.get(events=e)
            print(form.is_valid())
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request,'app/result.html',{'form':form})
            else:
                err="Please Enter Correct Data"
                content={'form':form,'err':err}
                return render(request,'app/form.html',content)
    else:
        form=Registration_Form()
        content={'form':form}
        return render(request,'app/form.html',content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **bulk_create** method.

Refer the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

```
eventlist=request.POST.getlist('events')
objs = [
    EventClass(
        file1=e.field1
    )
    for e in eventlist
]
eve = EventClass.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```